# Ajax not updating until page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm returning a partial view with jquery ajax that contents dropdowns that filters.
The problem I'm experiencing is when the partial view is load with ajax and I select an option to filter my other dropdowns my javascript doesn't fire,
but when reload the page and select an option to filter everything works and my code work as it should. Why do I need to reload my page for my script to fire?
Below is the blueprint of jquery ajax I use for all ajax requests:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            beforeSend: function () { $('.wait').show(); },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#tab3').html(data);
            },
            complete: function () { $('.wait').hide(); }
        });
```

Comment: you need delegated event on your element which fires the event

Comment: are you bind event correctly after you insert new html into DOM ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad can you shed some more light on your suggestion please..

Comment: @kag everything is bind in the partial view, all I'm doing is loading the view with the id's and elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registered handlers are only registered on pre-existing elements.
When you add new element you either need to create new handlers, or (better) do something like [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$( ".some-container-of-your-elements" ).on( "click", ".element-you-wish-to-listen", function() {
    console.log( "Magic!" );
});
```

Comment: therefore in my case it would be my div that's holding the partial view...`$('#tab3').html(data);`...#tab3 ?

Comment: Yes, it should be a div which is there from beginning (or rather from the time the "on" listener is being registered)